# How can you perform an integration test on message based processing?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

Assume I'm using pubsub or another message service. When a message is received, some processing is performed and the result written to the db.

Now in my integration test, I'm starting a pubsub emulator and send a message. Now I want to verify that the processing method is called and the right result in the database. That's no problem IF the processing happened. Now this might take a while. The only thing I came up with is emit message and then do `await().atMost(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS).until(() -> {...repository.find...}`

Obviously if the test platform is slow, this might fail. Is there another way except setting a high timeout?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a description (or maybe even code) on how messages are send and received in your system. Also explain how the whole system is setup and started. Include a description of your emulator as well, how you use it and how it differences from the real thing.

Comment: move these to integration tests and don't run them as part of the usual cycle? We do that with k8s integration tests and `kind`

Comment: @Progman How would that change the answer of the question though. There's the class `com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.Subscriber` which polls messages from a server. Upon tests, that server url is on localhost instead of an remote host. That's not really relevant for the question though. The trigger is a message being ready and then processed. Sending the message is part of the test. The polling is started by Spring boot, as the thread pool starts when spring is started. But the whole processing is async, hence problem with tests

Comment: @Regyn You might want to add these information to your question, not in a comment. These information are relevant as they might show what is available from an API perspective. As an example, you may be able to replace the (async) thread pool approach with a direct (sync) method call in the unit test. Another possible solution would be to replace (inject) the message queue system by an implementation where the message sent is consumed synchronously on the other end. That way your unit test is blocking while the message is handled. More detailed information (in your question) the better.